# Windows 10 Low battery settings not working

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop

Lenovo T430 with Windows 10.  Low battery settings don't work at all.  No warnings at 10% or 7%, no going to sleep.  Just keeps right on going until battery is dead then dies.

Any ideas on how to fix it.

Have tried altering settings to different levels as well as making sure windows updates are installed.

Answer (score 1):

To change settings of your battery go to

Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> Power Options

in here select the Plan shown on the battery meter, then on the right hand side of that option you will see "Change plan settings" click it.[image]

Now click the "Change advanced power settings, from here scroll to the bottom and expand the "Battery" option then expand the "Low battery notification" you want to turn this on like i have done here and this should now notify you when the battery is at 10% battery life.

[image]

Comment: I already tried this.

Comment: thats how you do it if you cannot see it you may need to check the Critical battery level and Low battery level

Comment: I can see those settings.  I've checked them.  The machine just acts like they are not set